# Django admin login page redirects to same page on correct login credentials

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm running a relatively fresh Django app that I haven't added much to. I tried to set up the admin (which I've done on plenty of other apps) to create some sample data while I build out the app, but whenever I try to log in with the super user account I created I get kicked back to the login screen.

When I enter incorrect credentials, I see the proper error message... I just can't get it to take me past the login screen to the admin when I have correct credentials. Has anyone else had this problem and been able to solve it? I'm at a dead end troubleshooting.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the runserver?

Comment: nope, no errors visible anywhere. it's as if the function is telling it to just go back to the login page, but I am just using the stock django-admin

Comment: hmm. what happens if you disable the other app(s) and rerun?

Comment: You might try clearing your cookies.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Check that `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` is not set while you are not using HTTPS.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like your cookies are messed up. Please start with clearing cookies in browser. If it doesn't help you can also check if your cookies configuration for project is correct. List of settings for cookies configuration can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#session-cookie-domain).

Comment: It turns out the problem was in my settings.py file. I prematurely added SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'mydomain.com' which I commented out until the site's on the production server/domain, and now it works fine.

Comment: clearing website data was the trick for me! `sessionid` was for my top level domain instead of staging.TLD.com; after clearing it got the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below settings for the [`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN):

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "yourdomain.com"
```